# sum of 2 div id value

Tags: jquery, sum

I have been given the below table in an .HTML file.

```
<tr>
<td><div id="number1"> 1 </div></td>
<td><div>+</div></td>
<td><div id="number2"> 2 </div></td>
</tr>
```

Without changing anything in the .HTML file, I need to add number 1 and number 2 to get a result through a .js file.

I came out with the following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

     var num1 = document.getElementById("number1").getAttribute.value;
     var num2 = document.getElementById("number2").getAttribute.value;

     var sum = num1 + num2;   

     alert(num1);
     alert(num2);
     alert(sum);
}):
```

I get num1 as undefined and num2 as undefined and I get the sum as NaN.

How can I get the value of the div id and add them together to get a result?

Comment: `...getAttribute` is a function. `...getAttribute.value` looks up the property `value` of the function `getAttribute`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: Use JavaScript parseInt() Function to convert string to int variable.Also trim space from string value.

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery, you can get the `text()` of each td and add them using `parseInt()`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var num1 = $('#number1').text();
  var num2 = $('#number2').text();
  var sum = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2);
  alert('sum is: ' + sum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td><div id="number1"> 1 </div></td>
    <td><div>+</div></td>
    <td><div id="number2"> 2 </div></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no attribute `value` on `div`, use `innerHTML` instead.

```
var num1 = document.getElementById("number1").innerHTML;
var num2 = document.getElementById("number2").innerHTML;
var sum = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2);   

alert(sum);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L84hL33d/

Then you need to use `parseInt`, because `innerHTML` (and `.value` too) return strings. `'1' + '2'` in JS is `'12'`, not 3 as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<tr>
<td><div id="number1"> 1 </div></td>
<td><div>+</div></td>
<td><div id="number2"> 2 </div></td>
</tr> 
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var docnumbers = new Array();
 var num1 = $("#number1").html();
    docnumbers.push(num1);
var num2 = $("#number2").html();
    docnumbers.push(num2);
var answerValue = 0; 

    for(i=0; i < docnumbers.length; i++) 
    { 
        answerValue += parseInt(docnumbers[i]);
    } 
    alert(answerValue);

});
</script>
```